# Adding a Geometric Progression (GP) on any segment of an array using Segment Trees

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, segment, fenwick-tree

I know how to make a Range Update on a Segment Tree involving Addition of a constant or Addition of an AP to any given segment of an array by lazy propagation and making subsequent queries about the sum of any given segment but cannot apply the same idea for geometric progressions.

How this can be achieved by using a segment trees in the same asymptotic time complexity `(log(N))`?

For example If the array is :
`a[1], a[2], .... , a[l],a[l+1]...a[r-1], a[r] ... a[n - 1], a[n]`
and if we update [l, r] with a common ratio of d then the updated array will be
`a[1], a[2], .... , a[l] + d, a[l+1] + d^2 ...a[r-1] + d^(l-r), a[r] + d^(l-r+1) ... a[n - 1], a[n]`

and one should still be able to make queries about sum of any segment in log(n).